# For loops in a dictionary, pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

Hi guys I have a question, for the variable `"image_datasets"` there is a for loop `for x in ['train', 'val']`. I have never seen the implementation of a for loop in a dict before.

```
data_transforms = {
'train': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
]),
'val': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
]),
}

data_dir = 'data/hymenoptera_data'
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=4,
                                             shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
              for x in ['train', 'val']}

dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) and it is iterating over a list.

The code

```py
dataloaders = {
    x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        image_datasets[x],
        batch_size=4,
        shuffle=True,
        num_workers=0
    )
    for x in ['train', 'val']
}
```

is equivalent to

```py
dataloaders = {
    'train': torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        image_datasets['train'],
        batch_size=4,
        shuffle=True,
        num_workers=0
    ),
    'val': torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        image_datasets['val'],
        batch_size=4,
        shuffle=True,
        num_workers=0
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called [dict comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) and there's also [list comprehensions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/):
https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/comprehensions.html

They basically function as you'd expect it:

```
Do X with x for x in List
```

and the result is then used as the input for a dict or list and so on.