# I am Trying to return a filtered dictionary from another dictionary in a function but my code is returning an empty dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I have to filter a dictionary and return a filtered item:
so in the following function
i have to return the filtered dictionary if the 2nd paramenter is a part of the key or return an empty dictionary.

Not sure why my code is returning empty dictionary by default

```py
def extractKey(dictionary, name):
    res = None
    for i in dictionary:
        if i == name:
            res = {name:dictionary[name]}
        if i != name:
            res = {}
      
    return res
```

Comment: You are redefining `res` at every step in your loop. That's why you are getting an empty result. Try using a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)

Comment: whats expected input and output btw?

Comment: also, the way you are iterating over a dict is **not** how a dict is supposed to be used. iterating over a dict to check for a specific key is not right approach in this case, at least if you're doing an exact name lookup, as opposed to a key search by a prefix for example.

Comment: If one of the provided answers helps, please make it as the correct answer. If we are missing information, please let us know so we can provide further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

For dictionaries, keys can be tested for membership. There are a few ways you can return a single key from the dictionary as a new dict…

Using membership testing…

```
def extractKey(dictionary, name):
    if name in dictionary:
        return {name: dictionary[name]}

    return {}
```

Using `.get` method…

```
def extractKey(dictionary, name):
    value = dictionary.get(name, None)
    if value is not None:
        return {name: value}
    
    return {}
```

I think the first method is the cleanest and easiest to read, but there are always more than one way to do the same thing!

The second method could break in the off chance the value of the key is actually `None` … something to keep in mind.

In the off chance you were needing to extract multiple keys…

```
def extractKeys(dictionary, names):
    res = {}
    for name in names:
        if name in dictionary:
            res[name] = dictionary[name]

    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand what your expected in/out is, but does this do something similar to what you are trying to accomplish? It returns a key-pair dictionary where the key matches the `name` argument.

```
def extractKey(dictionary, name):
    if name in dictionary:
        return {name:dictionary[name]}
    return {}
```

Comment: is the for loop technically necessary?

Comment: @rv.kvetch Good point, I simplified it further.

Comment: @JRose Your for loop is still adding unnecessary complexity. In Python 3 it will return the keys in the order they were added, if your key was the last key, it would iterate all keys first. In Python 2 keys are returned at random and the same could happen.

Comment: Hi @Jarvis, I was under the impression that dictionary membership lookup was O(1)? Would you mind linking me to a resource that indicates otherwise, or maybe I am not understanding your objection to my code?

Comment: Wow your code still had the for loop when I wrote that (after multiple times going in and out of the question on mobile). It’s all set now.