# Seeing if a certain element is in a 2nd list without using any

Tags: python

This is my first time submitting here, so please bear with me on formatting.

So, I have a normal list of strings like:

```py
name = ["Michael", "Helen", "Mike", "Joe", "Michael"]
```

I need to append these to another list if they don't repeat, and then later print out that list. So the next list would be like

```py
norepeat_list = ["Michael", "Helen", "Mike", "Joe"]
```

Which I've already done and didn't have issues with. The problem is I'm not just appending those names, each name has another value associated with it in another list of times (also strings), and I need that too. So I've been appending both the name and the times at the same time in a list like

```
norepeat_list.append(name[i], time[i])
```

Which then makes the result a 2d list. So I don't know how to make it so that the program checks each list in the list for the original name value, and the only solution I've found is 'any' or some import stuff, and I can't do that.

So far I have:

```
name = ["Michael", "Helen", "Mike", "Joe", "Michael"]
time = ["08:42:39", "08:39:56", "08:58:43", "09:04:03", "05:32:54"]

norepeat_list = []
for i in range(len(name[i])):
     if name[i] not in norepeat_list:
         norepeat_list.append(name[i])

for i in norepeat_list:
     print(i)
```

I've tried appending the timestamp at the same time and adding another layer of `for j in ...`, but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: Please take the time to format things correctly.

Comment: `student[i]`? Where is `student` I only see `name`?

Comment: If the elements' order doesn't matter, you can simply do `norepeat_list = list(set(name))`.

Comment: Sorry I typoed that and I really have no idea how to format things correctly here, this is my first time trying to use this.

Comment: You have 5 names (including a duplicate) in `name` but only **4** times in `time`?

Comment: at the risk of being a bit magic, `dict(zip(name, time))` might help.  note that dictionaries are the idiomatic way of encoding each "thing" should only appear once in this collection

Comment: The solution proposed by @SamMason is the best one IMHO, but OP should explain which time value should be held for the duplicated names.

Comment: @accdias have turned this into an answer. hopefully there's enough detail to explain how the magic works!

Answer (score 2):

The closest working code I can think of to your example is:

```
name = ["Michael", "Helen", "Mike", "Joe", "Michael"]
time = ["08:42:39", "08:39:56", "08:58:43", "09:04:03", "05:32:54"]

seen_names = []
norepeat_list = []
for i in range(len(name)):
     if name[i] not in seen_names:
         seen_names.append(name[i])
         norepeat_list.append((name[i], time[i]))

for name_time in norepeat_list:
     print(name_time)
```

but note that I've introduced an extra `seen_names` array to keep track of things you've already seen.  Having this extra list is bad for maintenance as you need to make sure both lists stay in sync with each other.  It's also bad for performance as checking whether an item is in a `list` takes time proportional to the length of the list, i.e. it gets slower for longer lists.  It would be better to use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#set) to track the items you've seen, as this wouldn't slow down as more items get added.

A more significant improvement would be to use a [dictionary/`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#dict) which allows you to associate arbitrary data (i.e. your times) with a set of items (i.e. your names).  A naive translation of the above code would be:

```
names = ["Michael", "Helen", "Mike", "Joe", "Michael"]
times = ["08:42:39", "08:39:56", "08:58:43", "09:04:03", "05:32:54"]

names_and_times = {}
for i in range(len(names)):
    if names[i] not in names_and_times:
        names_and_times[names[i]] = times[i]

for name_time in names_and_times.items():
    print(name_time)
```

Note that I've switched to a naming convention where plurals indicate a container of multiple values.

This could be improved by noticing that it repeats `names[i]` a lot. An way to reduce this would be to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
names_and_times = {}
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    if name not in names_and_times:
        names_and_times[name] = times[i]
```

or alternatively, you could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#zip) as many other answers have suggested:

```
names_and_times = {}
for name, time in zip(names, times):
    if name not in names_and_times:
        names_and_times[name] = time
```

another variant would be to exploit the fact that dictionaries can't have duplicates, so setting a dictionary item with the same item multiple times would just change the value rather than adding a new entry:

```
names_and_times = {}
for name, time in zip(names, times):
    names_and_times[name] = time
```

Note that this leaves the last time set for each name rather than the first.  Your question doesn't seem to express a preference, but this could be changed by iterating in reverse order:

```
names_and_times = {}
for name, time in zip(reversed(names), reversed(times)):
    names_and_times[name] = time
```

Next we could use a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14507591/1358308), which cleans the above up to:

```
names_and_times = {
    name: time
    for name, time in zip(names, time)
}
```

Finally we get to my original comment about things being magical, which exploits this usage of `zip` and the fact that passing an [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-iterable) of pairs causes the constructor of a `dict` to build a dictionary where the first item of each pair is the key and the second item is the value:

```
names_and_times = dict(zip(names, times))
```

or if you want the first `time` for each `name` you could do:

```
names_and_times = dict(zip(reversed(names), reversed(times)))
```

All of my examples leave `names_and_times` as a dictionary, but if you wanted to convert back to a list you can just do:

```
names_and_times = list(names_and_times.items())
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case I advise you use the "zip" function.

```
for n,t in zip(name,time):
    print(n,t)

this will zip the two lists together and you have access to the values of both lists.
```

Answer (score -1):

As you wrote "each name has another value associated with it in another list of times" I assume `name` and `time` has the same length, then something like this would work

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) produces a tuple of elements from both lists on the same position, so it will maintain the order, and skip elements with non-unique names (because they added to the seen):

```
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for n, t in zip(name, time):
        if n not in seen:
            seen.add(n)
            result.append((n, t))
    print(result)
```