# Update dictionary keys in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am updating the key names of a list of dictionaries in this way:

```
def update_keys(vars: list) -> None:
    keys = ["A", "V", "C"]
    for v in vars:
        for key in keys:
            if key in v:
                v[key.lower()] = v.pop(key)
```

Is there any pythonic way to do the key loop/update in one single line? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `vars`? Is it a `list` of `dict`s? Post a sample input and your expected output.

Comment: You can probably use the `zip()` function and combine with a dictionary comprehension.
`zip()` function: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip ; dict comprehension: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` with `lambda` to accomplish that, `vars[:]` will be updating the original list `vars`.

```py
def update_keys(vars: list) -> None:
    keys = ["A", "V", "C"]
    vars[:] = map(lambda v: {k if k not in keys else k.lower(): v[k] for k in v}, vars)
```

List comprehension with the use of `update` can also accomplish same result.

```py
def update_keys(vars: list) -> None:
    keys = ["A", "V", "C"]
    [v.update({key.lower(): v.pop(key) for key in keys if key in v}) for v in vars]
```

Comment: you should not use list comprehensions for side effects

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga realized that due to your helpful comment, so I provided an alternative approach. Thanks