# Conditionally including multiple keyword arguments in a function call

Tags: python

What is the 'pythonic' way to implement a waterfall if-statement like situation like this, when it applies to `kwargs`? I'm trying to avoid a situation where `c=None` is added to `kwargs` (because having `c` in the `kwargs` keys causes all sorts of problems downstream).

```
def run_something(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

def func(a = None, b=None, c=None):
    
    if a and b and c:
        run_something(a=a,b=b,c=c)
    elif a and b:        
        run_something(a=a,b=b)
    elif a:
        run_something(a=a)
    else:
        run_something()
```

I know the easy answer is that I could just do:

```
def func(**kwargs): 
    run_something(**kwargs)
```

however my particular use case doesn't make this easy

Comment: Why does your particular case not make this easy?

Comment: eh, long story... mostly I have too much code that simply looks for the key.  if 'x' in kwargs.keys():

Comment: It is often better to change *a lot of* badly designed code than to add *just a little bit* more of ugly code to work around it ;)

Comment: yea... I hear you.  Deadlines however dont...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, instead of doing tests like `if a:` I am guessing what you really want to do is only pass the *a* argument of it isn't `None` so testing `if a is not None:` will pass a value for *a* that is 0 or an empty string, i.e. anything other than the default. So this is what I would do:

```py
def run_something(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

def func(a = None, b=None, c=None):
    d = {}
    if a is not None:
        d['a'] = a
    if b is not None:
        d['b'] = b
    if c is not None:
        d['c'] = c
    run_something(**d)

func(c=7, b=4)
```

Prints:

```None
{'b': 4, 'c': 7}
```

Note that the above handles any combination of passed arguments, which your "waterfall" `if` statements do not. If you really want to test for any non-False value as in your original code, then of course you can do:

```py
def run_something(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

def func(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    d = {}
    if a:
        d['a'] = a
    if b:
        d['b'] = b
    if c:
        d['c'] = c
    run_something(**d)

func(c=7, b=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def run_something(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)


def func(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    kwargs = {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c}
    run_something(**{key_word: arg for key_word, arg in kwargs.items() if arg is not None})


func()                  # {}
func("a")               # {'a': 'a'}
func("a", "b")          # {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
func("a", "b", "c")     # {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}
func(b="b")             # {'b': 'b'}
func("a", c="c")        # {'a': 'a', 'c': 'c'}
func(b="b", c="c")      # {'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}
func(c="c")             # {'c': 'c'}
```

this will handle any combination of a b and c

I used dictionary comprehension.
in case you don't know what it means you can check this out [python dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)

Answer (score -1):

Short and sweet:

```python
def foo(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    run_something(
        **({ 'a': a } if a else {}),
        **({ 'b': b } if b else {}),
        **({ 'c': c } if c else {}),
    )
```

Whether it’s ‘pythonic’, I will not say.  Personally, I find it a meaningless notion, vague and ad-hoc at best and self-contradictory at worst.