# Get date and time when photo was taken from EXIF data using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I can [get the EXIF data from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image) using PIL, but how can I get the date and time that the photo was taken?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Found the answer eventually, the tag I needed was [36867](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif/datetimeoriginal.html):

```
from PIL import Image
def get_date_taken(path):
    exif = Image.open(path)._getexif()
    if not exif:
        raise Exception('Image {0} does not have EXIF data.'.format(path))
    return exif[36867]
```

This works for me on both the old "PIL", and the new "Pillow" fork.

Comment: http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif.html This link give the value information for each tag.

Comment: another approach is using GExiv2 as shown here: http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2014/01/python-fixing-my-photo-library-dates.html

Comment: This will crash with "KeyError: 36867" if the image does not contain the EXIF information for the image creation date.

Answer (score 24):

I like to use `exif-py` because it's pure-python, does not require compilation/installation, and works with both python 2.x and 3.x making it ideal for bundling with small portable python applications.

Link:
https://github.com/ianare/exif-py

Example to get the date and time a photo was taken:

```
import exifread
with open('image.jpg', 'rb') as fh:
    tags = exifread.process_file(fh, stop_tag="EXIF DateTimeOriginal")
    dateTaken = tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"]
    return dateTaken
```

Answer (score 21):

This has changed slightly in more recent versions of Pillow (6.0+ I believe).

They added a public method `getexif()` that you should use. The previous version was private and experimental (`_getexif()`).

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('path/to/image.jpg')
exif = im.getexif()
creation_time = exif.get(36867)
```

Comment: Note:  If no date is found, `exif.get()` will return `None`. If a date is found, `exif.get()` returns the date as a `String`. To convert to a datetime, use `datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')` (Conversion code via [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62077871/3357935))

Answer (score 9):

`ExifTags.TAGS` is a mapping from tag to tag name. You can use it to create a map of tag names to values.

On this particular picture, there are a few different "date" properties (`DateTime`, `DateTimeOriginal`, `DateTimeDigitized`) that could be used.

```py
import json
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
from datetime import datetime

def main(filename):
    image_exif = Image.open(filename)._getexif()
    if image_exif:
        # Make a map with tag names
        exif = { ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v for k, v in image_exif.items() if k in ExifTags.TAGS and type(v) is not bytes }
        print(json.dumps(exif, indent=4))
        # Grab the date
        date_obj = datetime.strptime(exif['DateTimeOriginal'], '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(date_obj)
    else:
        print('Unable to get date from exif for %s' % filename)
```

Output:

```
{
    "DateTimeOriginal": "2008:11:15 19:36:24",
    "DateTimeDigitized": "2008:11:15 19:36:24",
    "ColorSpace": 1,
    "ExifImageWidth": 3088,
    "SceneCaptureType": 0,
    "ExifImageHeight": 2320,
    "SubjectDistanceRange": 2,
    "ImageDescription": "               ",
    "Make": "Hewlett-Packard                ",
    "Model": "HP Photosmart R740             ",
    "Orientation": 1,
    "DateTime": "2008:11:15 19:36:24",
    ...
}
2008-11-15 19:36:24
```

Answer (score 4):

I create a function (`get_exif`) that can get attributes more easily.

## USAGE

```py
your_date_time: str = get_exif(Path('test.jpg'), 'DateTimeOriginal')
# your_date_time = get_exif(Path('test.jpg'), 0x9003)  # same as above
```

## get_exif

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, List, Tuple
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ExifTags


def get_exif(file_path: Path,
             search_list: Union[int, str, List, Tuple] = None,
             ignore_error=True
             ) -> Union[int, PIL.Image.Exif, List]:
    """
    :param file_path: image path
    :param search_list: if you want to get some property, then you can pass the id or name, it will return by order.
    :param ignore_error:
    :return:
        int: -1 FileNotFoundError, or exif is None
        PIL.Image.Exif: when the `search_list` is None, return the whole Exif
    """
    tag_by_id: dict = PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
    try:
        im: PIL.Image.Image = PIL.Image.open(str(file_path))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        if ignore_error:
            return -1
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError(file_path)
    exif: PIL.Image.Exif = im.getexif()
    if not exif:
        if ignore_error:
            return -1
        else:
            raise ValueError("exif is None")
    if search_list is None:
        return exif
    tag_by_name = {tag_by_id[dec_value]: exif[dec_value] for dec_value in exif if dec_value in tag_by_id}
    result_list = []
    if not isinstance(search_list, (list, tuple)):
        search_list = [search_list]
    for key in search_list:
        if isinstance(key, int):
            result_list.append(exif.get(key, None))
            continue
        try:
            dec_value = int(key, 16)
            result_list.append(exif.get(dec_value, None))
            continue
        except ValueError:
            ...
        result_list.append(tag_by_name.get(key, None))
    return result_list if len(result_list) > 1 else result_list[0]
```

## MORE TEST

```py
import unittest

class ExifTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        exif: PIL.Image.Exif = get_exif(Path('test.jpg'))  # same as the ``PIL.Image.open().getexif()``

        # get specify attribute only
        date_t_ori1 = get_exif(Path('test.jpg'), 0x9003)
        date_t_ori2 = get_exif(Path('test.jpg'), '0x9003', )  # hex string is ok too.
        date_t_ori3 = get_exif(Path('test.jpg'), 'DateTimeOriginal')  # Give name is also working.
        self.assertTrue(date_t_ori1 == date_t_ori2 == date_t_ori3)

        # You can get multiple values at once. If the key does not exist, it returns None.
        date_t_ori4, img_length, _, __ = get_exif(Path('test.jpg'),
                                                  (36867, 'ImageLength', 'NoteExitName', -12345))

        # Occurring error return -1 (by default ignore_error=True)
        self.assertEqual(-1, get_exif(Path('not exist.jpg')))  # FileNotFoundError
        self.assertEqual(-1, get_exif(Path('no_exif_tag.jpg')))  # ValueError

        self.assertRaises(FileNotFoundError, get_exif, Path('not exist.jpg'), ignore_error=False)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, get_exif, Path('no_exif_tag.jpg'), ignore_error=False)
```

## note

This [website](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif.html) is good, but if you want to get the full list, you should reference [PIL.ExifTags.py](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/c40b0e54267d148fd6d1bb8523ec0f8fe8e44cf3/src/PIL/ExifTags.py#L125), see below,

```
# ExifTags.py

# Maps EXIF tags to tag names.

TAGS = {
    # possibly incomplete
    0x000B: "ProcessingSoftware",
    0x00FE: "NewSubfileType",
    0x00FF: "SubfileType",
    0x0100: "ImageWidth",
    0x0101: "ImageLength",
    0x0102: "BitsPerSample",
    ...
    0xA430: "CameraOwnerName",  # <-- The website does not record it. (The website record last tag is A420.)
    0xA431: "BodySerialNumber",
    0xA432: "LensSpecification",
    0xA433: "LensMake",
    0xA434: "LensModel",
}


# Maps EXIF GPS tags to tag names.

GPSTAGS = {
    0: "GPSVersionID",
    1: "GPSLatitudeRef",
    2: "GPSLatitude",
    3: "GPSLongitudeRef",
    4: "GPSLongitude",
    5: "GPSAltitudeRef",
    6: "GPSAltitude",
    7: "GPSTimeStamp",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
try:
    import PIL
    import PIL.Image as PILimage
    from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageEnhance
    from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS
except ImportError as err:
    exit(err)


class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, img):
        self.img = img
        self.get_exif_data()
        self.date =self.get_date_time()
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def get_exif_data(self):
        exif_data = {}
        info = self.img._getexif()
        if info:
            for tag, value in info.items():
                decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
                if decoded == "GPSInfo":
                    gps_data = {}
                    for t in value:
                        sub_decoded = GPSTAGS.get(t, t)
                        gps_data[sub_decoded] = value[t]

                    exif_data[decoded] = gps_data
                else:
                    exif_data[decoded] = value
        self.exif_data = exif_data
        # return exif_data 

    def get_date_time(self):
        if 'DateTime' in self.exif_data:
            date_and_time = self.exif_data['DateTime']
            return date_and_time 


def main():
    date = image.date
    print(date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        img = PILimage.open(path + filename)
        image = Worker(img)
        date = image.date
        print(date)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```