# use python to get the size of an image (NEF and jpeg)

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, image-size

When taking pictures with my NIKON D5100 I shoot both in raw (.NEF) and jpeg. Most of the time I don't use that raw image, but from time to time I do.

To ease the tagging and selection of the images I want to automatically move the raw images to  a different location. As a check in the python script to move the raw images I want to compare the image resolution of the jpeg to the raw resolution. So far I have not found a method that returns the same size for the raw and jpeg image.

This is a summary of the methods I tried using Python:

```
from PIL import Image as PIL_Image
from wand.image import Image as wand_Image
import imageio
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import exifread
from collections import namedtuple


def get_exif(fname):
    # http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/28/getting-photo-metadata-exif-using-python/
    ret = {}
    i = PIL_Image.open(fname)
    info = i._getexif()
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        ret[decoded] = value
    return ret


def get_imagesize_PIL(fname):
    with PIL_Image.open(fname) as im:
        return im.size


def get_imagesize_PIL2(fname):
    exif = get_exif(fname)
    return exif['ExifImageHeight'], exif['ExifImageWidth']


def get_imagesize_PIL3(fname):
    with PIL_Image.open(fname) as im:
        return im.info


def get_imagesize_imageioraw(fname):
    return imageio.imread(fname, "raw").shape[:-1]


def get_imagesize_imageio(fname):
    return imageio.imread(fname).shape[:-1]


def get_imagesize_exifread(fname):  # http://stackoverflow.com/a/18027454/1562285
    exif = exifread.process_file(open(fname, 'rb'), strict=True)
    return exif['Image XResolution'], exif['Image YResolution']


def get_imagesize_exifread2(fname):
    exif = exifread.process_file(open(fname, 'rb'), strict=True)
    return exif['Image ImageLength'], exif['Image ImageWidth']


def get_imagesize_exifread3(fname):
    exif = exifread.process_file(open(fname, 'rb'), strict=True)
    return exif['MakerNote CropHiSpeed']


def get_imagesize_exifread4(fname):
    exif = exifread.process_file(open(fname, 'rb'), strict=True)
    return exif['EXIF ExifImageLength'], exif['EXIF ExifImageWidth']


def get_imagesize_wand(fname):
    with wand_Image(filename=fname) as img:
        return img.size


def get_imagesize_wand2(fname):
    with wand_Image(filename=fname) as img:
        return img.page


# def get_imagesize_wand3(fname):
#     with wand_Image(filename=fname) as img:
#         return img.info


def get_imagesize_libraw(fname):
    with rawkit_Raw(filename=fname) as raw:
        print(raw.Metadata.height, raw.Metadata.width)

def create_eval(fmethod, fname):
    try:
        eval_str = "get_imagesize_%s('%s')" % (fmethod, fname)
        # print(eval_str)
        return eval(eval_str)
    except BaseException as e:
        return str(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    file_nt = namedtuple("image_file", "filename tag")
    filetypes = list()
    filetypes.append(file_nt("20120917_131155 DSC_0159.JPG", "jpeg"))
    filetypes.append(file_nt("20120917_131155 DSC_0159.NEF", "nef"))
    # filetypes.append(file_nt("20120917_131155 DSC_0159.xmp", "xmp"))
    # @TODO: add method to check into xmp?

    methods = [
        "PIL",
        "PIL2",
        "PIL3",
        "imageioraw",
        "imageio",
        "exifread",
        "exifread2",
        "exifread3",
        "exifread4",
        "wand",
        "wand2",
        "libraw",
    ]

    for method in methods:
        for filetype in filetypes:
            print("%s %s: %s" % (filetype.tag, method, repr(create_eval(method, filetype.filename))))
# @TODO: add timers to check the fastest method
```

with this result

```
jpeg PIL: (4928, 3264)
nef PIL: (160, 120)
jpeg PIL2: (3264, 4928)
nef PIL2: "'TiffImageFile' object has no attribute '_getexif'"
jpeg PIL3: {'exif': b'Exif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x0b\x01\x0f\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x94\x01\x10\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\xa8\x01\x12\x00...'}
nef PIL3: {'compression': 'raw', 'dpi': (300.0, 300.0)}
jpeg imageioraw: 'Could not load bitmap "C:\\Users\\maarten\\PycharmProjects\\fotosize\\20120917_131155 DSC_0159.JPG": LibRaw : failed to open input stream (unknown format)'
nef imageioraw: (3280, 4948)
jpeg imageio: (3264, 4928)
nef imageio: (120, 160)
jpeg exifread: ((0x011A) Ratio=300 @ 180, (0x011B) Ratio=300 @ 188)
nef exifread: ((0x011A) Ratio=300 @ 356, (0x011B) Ratio=300 @ 364)
jpeg exifread2: "'Image ImageLength'"
nef exifread2: ((0x0101) Long=120 @ 42, (0x0100) Long=160 @ 30)
jpeg exifread3: (0x001B) Short=[0, 4992, 3280, 4992, 3280, 0, 0] @ 1676
nef exifread3: (0x001B) Short=[0, 4992, 3280, 4992, 3280, 0, 0] @ 1852
jpeg exifread4: ((0xA003) Short=3264 @ 526, (0xA002) Short=4928 @ 514)
nef exifread4: "'EXIF ExifImageLength'"
jpeg wand: (4928, 3264)
nef wand: (4948, 3280)
jpeg wand2: (4928, 3264, 0, 0)
nef wand2: (4948, 3280, 0, 0)
jpeg libraw: 'Cannot find LibRaw on your system!'
nef libraw: 'Cannot find LibRaw on your system!'
```

The ones returning 160x120 is probably for the embedded preview image

Windows explorer does seem to find the correct dimensions
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKSkF.png)

I've tried rawkit too, but it doesn't seem to find the libraw. I found no clear instructions on how to 'install' libraw, but I tried copying it named as libraw.dll or Raw.dll into "C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin", and when I try

```
In[3]: ctypes.util.find_library("libraw")
Out[3]: 
'C:\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\libraw.dll'
In[4]: ctypes.util.find_library("Raw")
Out[4]: 
'C:\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\Raw.dll'
```

it does seem to find it.

Does anyone know what method I can use? It doesn't have to be the same method for the jpeg and the NEF-image, but that'd be welcome.

At this moment performance isn't a key issue, but the faster the better

The code and a sample image can be found in [my github repo](https://github.com/vadella/fotosize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a different solution employing win32com thanks to [this postP](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/802917-finding-file-details)

```
from pprint import pprint
import win32com.client
import os
import re
from pathlib import Path


# https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/802917-finding-file-details

def _get_dimensions_subdir(folder_name):
    sh = win32com.client.Dispatch('Shell.Application')
    ns = sh.NameSpace(folder_name)
    results = {}
    for c in range(0, 255):
        colname = ns.GetDetailsOf(None, c)
        if colname == 'Dimensions':
            for i in ns.Items():
                dimensions = ns.GetDetailsOf(i, c)
                if dimensions:
                    results[ns.GetDetailsOf(i, 0)] = _parse_dimensions(dimensions)
    return results


dim_pat = re.compile("(\d+) x (\d+)")


def _parse_dimensions(dim):
    x, y = dim_pat.findall(dim)[0]
    return int(x), int(y)


def get_combined_results(subdirs, src_path):
    for subdir in subdirs:
        dim = _get_dimensions_subdir(str(subdir))
        if dim:
            yield str(subdir.relative_to(src_path)), dim


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DATA_DIR = Path(".")
    subdirs = DATA_DIR.glob("**")

    results = get_combined_results(subdirs, DATA_DIR)
    pprint(dict(results))
```

Answer (score 0):

**ImageMagick** identifies them as follows:

```
identify sign.jpg
```

**Output**

```
sign.jpg JPEG 4928x3264 4928x3264+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4.401MB 0.000u 0:00.009
```

and for the NEF:

```
identify ~/Desktop/*NEF
```

**Output**

```
/Users/... NEF 4948x3280 4948x3280+0+0 16-bit sRGB 75.99MB 0.010u 0:00.009
```