# Python - How to list tags from jpg EXIF data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jpeg, exif

I've got a bunch of images I'm planning to use for something, and it would be very helpful if I could sort them all by giving them tags that a Python script can read. I tried a few methods from [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image), but none of them return the data I need. Here's what I've tried:

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ExifTags
import exifread

dir = "C:\directory\\"
image = "image_name.jpg"
image_dir = dir + image
img = Image.open(image_dir)

#Attempt 1 - using PIL
exif_data = img._getexif()

print(exif_data)

#Attempt 2 - using exifread
f = open(image_dir)
tags = exifread.process_file(f)

print(tags)

#Attemp 3 - using PIL
exif = {
    PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
    for k, v in img._getexif().items()
    if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
}

print(exif)
```

The results are a bit long and messy (Attempt 1 returns a very long dictionary with a bunch of repeating "\x00\" so I won't post that here):

- Attempt 2 - `{'Image XPKeywords': (0x9C9E) Byte=[] @ 30, 'EXIF Padding': (0xEA1C) Undefined=[] @ 2128, 'Image ExifOffset': (0x8769) Long=2110 @ 18, 'Image Padding': (0xEA1C) Undefined=[] @ 50}`
- Attempt 3 - `{'ExifOffset': 2110, 'XPKeywords': 'e\x00x\x00a\x00m\x00p\x00l\x00e\x00;\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00\x00\x00'}`

The tags themselves are "example" and "test." Any tips on what I can do differently?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try running this as a Python 3 script. I just ran your attempt #1 code against

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Stonehenge.jpg
```

and it worked, giving the results:

```
{40963: 472, 305: 'Adobe Photoshop CS Windows', 274: 1, 40962: 709, 40961: 65535, 296: 2, 34665: 164, 282: (120, 1), 283: (120, 1), 306: '2005:10:13 15:32:07'}
```

Note: I was using Pillow, the fork of PIL from - http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/installation.html