# How to read image description from the image with c++ or python?

Tags: image, opencv

I wish to read image description text from the image property tab (right click) with c++ or python.

[image]

Is there anyway to do it? 
Looks like Opencv is not supporting it, I guess.
BTW, my OS is ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Ubuntu, you probably have **ImageMagick** installed and that has a program called `identify` within the suite. You can just run the following in a Terminal at the command-line, or you could run a Python subprocess and grab its output:

```
identify -verbose someImage.jpg
```

**Sample Output**

```
Image: /Users/mark/Desktop/IMG_2326.JPG
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 3264x2448+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 45.3333x34
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 8-bit
    Blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 7990272
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 139.125 (0.545587)
      standard deviation: 62.0934 (0.243503)
      kurtosis: -0.948773
      skewness: -0.255567
      entropy: 0.980761
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 129.827 (0.509124)
      standard deviation: 63.4802 (0.248942)
      kurtosis: -0.744472
      skewness: -0.322559
      entropy: 0.978628
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 121.768 (0.477522)
      standard deviation: 63.6425 (0.249578)
      kurtosis: -1.14208
      skewness: 0.0243162
      entropy: 0.980614
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 130.24 (0.510744)
      standard deviation: 63.4733 (0.248915)
      kurtosis: -0.968273
      skewness: -0.18575
      entropy: 0.980001
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 3264x2448+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 96
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2017-05-31T13:53:16+01:00
    date:modify: 2014-09-23T08:22:25+01:00
    exif:ApertureValue: 4845/1918
    exif:BrightnessValue: 6155/1061
    exif:ColorSpace: 1
    exif:ComponentsConfiguration: 1, 2, 3, 0
    exif:DateTime: 2014:09:23 08:22:25
    exif:DateTimeDigitized: 2014:09:23 08:22:25
    exif:DateTimeOriginal: 2014:09:23 08:22:25
    exif:ExifImageLength: 2448
    exif:ExifImageWidth: 3264
    exif:ExifOffset: 204
    exif:ExifVersion: 48, 50, 50, 49
    exif:ExposureMode: 0
    exif:ExposureProgram: 2
    exif:ExposureTime: 1/120
    exif:Flash: 24
    exif:FlashPixVersion: 48, 49, 48, 48
    exif:FNumber: 12/5
    exif:FocalLength: 103/25
    exif:FocalLengthIn35mmFilm: 33
    exif:GPSAltitude: 10003/299
    exif:GPSAltitudeRef: 0
    exif:GPSInfo: 946
    exif:GPSLatitude: 51/1, 51/1, 347/100
    exif:GPSLatitudeRef: N
    exif:GPSLongitude: 2/1, 12/1, 1992/100
    exif:GPSLongitudeRef: W
    exif:GPSTimeStamp: 7/1, 22/1, 2456/100
    exif:ISOSpeedRatings: 64
    exif:Make: Apple
    exif:MakerNote: 65, 112, 112, 108, 101, 32, 105, 79, 83, 0, 0, 1, 77, 77, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 104, 0, 0, 0, 92, 0, 4, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 208, 0, 6, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 218, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 98, 112, 108, 105, 115, 116, 48, 48, 212, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 89, 116, 105, 109, 101, 115, 99, 97, 108, 101, 85, 101, 112, 111, 99, 104, 85, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 85, 102, 108, 97, 103, 115, 18, 59, 154, 202, 0, 16, 0, 19, 0, 0, 18, 143, 64, 67, 109, 189, 16, 1, 8, 17, 27, 33, 39, 45, 50, 52, 61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 63
    exif:MeteringMode: 5
    exif:Model: iPhone 5
    exif:Orientation: 1
    exif:ResolutionUnit: 2
    exif:SceneCaptureType: 0
    exif:SceneType: 1
    exif:SensingMethod: 2
    exif:ShutterSpeedValue: 5567/806
    exif:Software: 7.1.2
    exif:SubjectArea: 1631, 1223, 1795, 1077
    exif:SubSecTimeDigitized: 918
    exif:SubSecTimeOriginal: 918
    exif:thumbnail:Compression: 6
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormat: 1210
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 12195
    exif:thumbnail:ResolutionUnit: 2
    exif:thumbnail:XResolution: 72/1
    exif:thumbnail:YResolution: 72/1
    exif:WhiteBalance: 0
    exif:XResolution: 72/1
    exif:YCbCrPositioning: 1
    exif:YResolution: 72/1
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
    signature: 84dc83ac4ff07920155036d321be9b8fe687be8b5eb68a76e20518b3e6f048f8
    unknown: 103/25, 103/25, 12/5, 12/5
  Profiles:
    Profile-exif: 16380 bytes
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 3.9071MiB
  Number pixels: 7.99027M
  Pixels per second: 47.0016MB
  User time: 0.150u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.170
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-6 Q16 x86_64 2017-05-15 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

---

Another option is `exiftool`, which you run like this at the command-line, and which you could also run as a subprocess in Python:

```
exiftool ~/Desktop/IMG_2326.JPG
```

**Sample Output**

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.50
File Name                       : IMG_2326.JPG
Directory                       : /Users/mark/Desktop
File Size                       : 3.9 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:09:23 08:22:25+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2017:05:31 13:57:20+01:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2017:05:31 13:53:16+01:00
File Permissions                : rw-------
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Make                            : Apple
Camera Model Name               : iPhone 5
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : 7.1.2
Modify Date                     : 2014:09:23 08:22:25
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Exposure Time                   : 1/120
F Number                        : 2.4
Exposure Program                : Program AE
ISO                             : 64
Exif Version                    : 0221
Date/Time Original              : 2014:09:23 08:22:25
Create Date                     : 2014:09:23 08:22:25
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/120
Aperture Value                  : 2.4
Brightness Value                : 5.801131008
Metering Mode                   : Multi-segment
Flash                           : Auto, Did not fire
Focal Length                    : 4.1 mm
Subject Area                    : 1631 1223 1795 1077
Run Time Scale                  : 1000000000
Run Time Epoch                  : 0
Run Time Value                  : 20406467784125
Run Time Flags                  : Valid
Sub Sec Time Original           : 918
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 918
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 3264
Exif Image Height               : 2448
Sensing Method                  : One-chip color area
Scene Type                      : Directly photographed
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
White Balance                   : Auto
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 33 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Lens Info                       : 4.12mm f/2.4
Lens Make                       : Apple
Lens Model                      : iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4
GPS Latitude Ref                : North
GPS Longitude Ref               : West
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
GPS Time Stamp                  : 07:22:24.56
Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
Thumbnail Offset                : 1222
Thumbnail Length                : 12195
Image Width                     : 3264
Image Height                    : 2448
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Aperture                        : 2.4
GPS Altitude                    : 33.4 m Above Sea Level
GPS Latitude                    : 51 deg 51' 3.47" N
GPS Longitude                   : 2 deg 12' 19.92" W
GPS Position                    : 51 deg 51' 3.47" N, 2 deg 12' 19.92" W
Image Size                      : 3264x2448
Megapixels                      : 8.0
Run Time Since Power Up         : 5:40:06
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 8.0
Shutter Speed                   : 1/120
Create Date                     : 2014:09:23 08:22:25.918
Date/Time Original              : 2014:09:23 08:22:25.918
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 12195 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.004 mm
Field Of View                   : 57.2 deg
Focal Length                    : 4.1 mm (35 mm equivalent: 33.0 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : 1.89 m
Light Value                     : 10.1
```

---

Another option is `exiv2` which is available from [here](http://www.exiv2.org) and also has various library APIs available.

I have not used it and cannot endorse it, but there is also [a Python interface to exiv2](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/tutorial.html).

---

In case you wanted a hand on Python subprocesses, you do this sort of thing:

```
import subprocess

...
...

p = subprocess.Popen(['identify -verbose someImage.jpg'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
retcode = p.wait()
data = p.stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

These properties should be stored in [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) data.

In Python, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image) for some code to read Exif data.

Answer (score -1):

With Opencv we can able to read image type,width,height,Depth but we cant able to read other parameters related to ISo,ShutterSpeed,Brightness,Description and Date Modified,Created.
If you want to get that information you can get it using C#