# preserve exif data while resizing images in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I am resizing an image using PIL but the EXIF info is not getting preserved. I was going through answers in stack overflow  but all are very old answers and dont seem to be working now. All are using pyexiv2 but I cant find it on google.
Can someone suggest some method /to do the above in python 2.7?

```
def imageresize(srcfile, destfile, newwid):
    img = Image.open(srcfile)
    print img
    s = img.size 
    ratio = (float(newwid)/s[0])
    newhght = int(ratio*s[1])
    img.resize((newwid, newhght),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(destfile)
```

Comment: why not read the EXIF information from the source image and write it to the destination image?

Comment: I am not able to get a suitable library to read and write EXIF info. Can you suggest @sid-m

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image

Comment: @sid-m It is very helpful for reading EXIF tags but how do I write back the EXIF tags into the resized image with all tags same except for the width and height tags?

Answer (score 0):

```
if "exif" in img.info:
    img.save(destfile, exif=img.info["exif"])
else:
    img.save(destfile)
```

Or use [Piexif](http://piexif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: this code snippet is not working . It is not resizing the images that have exif data.

Comment: can you suggest some method other than piexif ?