# Why is my _getexif() returning None?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif, nonetype

I have the following `Python` script:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

img = Image.open('/path/1.jpg')
info = img._getexif()
print info
```

Why is `info` returned as `None`, although that I made sure that `img` has been read?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about PIL, but be careful using methods prefixed with an underscore; they're intented to be protected/private/internal, and subject to change in unpredictable ways. If there's a public method to get what you're after, try using that instead.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? From this link (although this could be outdated now): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image it seems PIL's _getexif() might not work in later version of Python. You might want to look at Pillow - a fork from PIL, compatible with Python 3.

Comment: @Ryry thanks for your kind reply. I'm using Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue was because the image I was reading seemed not to have exif data in the first place, as opposed to the images taken using a mobile phone camera for instance, which the image I was reading apparently hasn't.