# Python Program using PIL Refuses to Run Second Time

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, thumbnails, exif

I wrote this short program to convert JPEG files in a folder into thumbnails.

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ExifTags

size = (800,800)

for infile in glob.glob("c:/Users/ascklee/Desktop/PIL_test/*.jpg"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)

    exif = {
        ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
        for k, v in im._getexif().items()
        if k in ExifTags.TAGS
    }

    for i in exif:
        print (i, ":", exif[i])

    if exif['Orientation'] == 3:
        image=im.rotate(180, expand=True)
    elif exif['Orientation'] == 6:
        image=im.rotate(270, expand=True)
    elif exif['Orientation'] == 8:
        image=im.rotate(90, expand=True)

    image.thumbnail(size)
    image.save(file + "_TN" + ".jpg", "JPEG")
```

It is really strange because the first time, the program runs fine.  It fails after the first image if I run it again, without first deleting the thumbnails it created the first time round.

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ascklee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Creating 
Thumbnails (orientation - 4).py", line 14, in <module>
    for k, v in im._getexif().items()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I am using IDLE 3.7.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my \_getexif() returning None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021950/why-is-my-getexif-returning-none)

Answer (score 0):

one of the images is returning `None` to the `im._getexif()` call, it's possible it doesn't have any exif tags, you can work around this by changing your code to look like this

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ExifTags

size = (800,800)

for infile in glob.glob("c:/Users/ascklee/Desktop/PIL_test/*.jpg"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)

    try:
        exif = {
            ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
            for k, v in im._getexif().items()
            if k in ExifTags.TAGS
         }

    except AttributeError:
        print('this image has no exif tags')
        continue

    for i in exif:
        print (i, ":", exif[i])

    if exif['Orientation'] == 3:
        image=im.rotate(180, expand=True)
    elif exif['Orientation'] == 6:
        image=im.rotate(270, expand=True)
    elif exif['Orientation'] == 8:
        image=im.rotate(90, expand=True)

    image.thumbnail(size)
    image.save(file + "_TN" + ".jpg", "JPEG")
```

Comment: Dear @vencaslac, Thank you very much for your explanation.  You solved it!