# Access EXIF data using pillow without accessing a protected member

Tags: python, exif, python-imaging-library, pylint

The examples I have found for using [pillow](http://python-pillow.github.io/) to access EXIF metadata for an image make use of the protected member `_getexif()` of PIL.Image. Pylint will complain about this with the following warning:

> [W0212(protected-access), functionname] Access to a protected member
>   _getexif of a client class

Is there a way to get at the EXIF data for an Image without going through a protected member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_getexif()` is underscored because they don't want to commit to it always working the way it does now - the code says "This method is highly experimental, and is likely to be replaced with something better in a future version."  Although, as far as I know, it's said that in PIL for *ages*.

So your choices are:

- suppress the lint warning
- get the raw (unparsed) exif data with `i.info.get('exif')` and parse it yourself, possibly with code ripped out of Pillow
- use a supported exif library like [ExifRead](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead)

**edit**: really "don't want to commit to it always working the way it does now" is underselling it a bit - `_getexif()` is for the library's own (very limited) internal use, and they recognise that parsing *real* exifs found in the wild, and giving a reliable result for all (even the weird ones) is a more significant undertaking than they're willing to sign up for.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow references use of `_getexif()` in ["In Python, how do I read the exif data for an image?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image#4765242) Using ExifRead seems to be the more robust approach despite the accepted best answer to the other post.

Comment: It's not that `_getexif()` is *wrong*, it's that it's a bit risky (risk that it changes, risk that it's removed, and risk because it's not a very well supported or documented feature).  I'm not convinced that most people care about most of the data you get from EXIF anyway.  Beyond time-and-place taken, and maybe exposure/shutter info, it's fairly dull and esoteric stuff.

Comment: _getexif has been labelled as experimental ever since it was first implemented in PIL 1.1.4 in 2003! http://effbot.org/zone/pil-changes-114.htm