# Can't keep image exif data when editing it with opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to crop images in python, and need keep the exif data when I crop them, but I lose the exif data of the original image when I save the resulting cropped image, how can I avoid this from happening?
The code I've been running:

```
from imutils import face_utils
import imutils
import numpy as np
import collections
import dlib
import cv2
import glob
import os

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
PREDICTOR_PATH = "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)

def face_remap(shape):
    remapped_image = cv2.convexHull(shape)
    return remapped_image


def faceCrop(imagePattern):

    imgList=glob.glob(imagePattern)
    if len(imgList)<=0:
        print ('No Images Found')
        return
    for img in imgList:
        image = cv2.imread(img)
        image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        out_face = np.zeros_like(image)
        rects = detector(gray, 1)
        for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
            shape = predictor(gray, rect)
            shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
            #initialize mask array
            remapped_shape = np.zeros_like(shape) 
            feature_mask = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))   
            # we extract the face
            remapped_shape = face_remap(shape)
            cv2.fillConvexPoly(feature_mask, remapped_shape[0:27], 1)
            feature_mask = feature_mask.astype(np.bool)
            out_face[feature_mask] = image[feature_mask]
            fname,ext=os.path.splitext(img)
            cv2.imwrite(fname+'_crop'+ext, out_face)
    print ('Listo \n')                
faceCrop('/Users/alejandroramirez/Documents/imagenes nuevas/2/*.JPG')
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Off course, I uploaded the code in the question

Comment: OpenCV won't help you with that. Find some other python library that lets you read and write EXIF data. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4764932/3962537) may be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, maybe pillow would be usefull?

Answer (score 0):

When you load an image into OpenCV you lost all the metadata due to the fact that the image is converted into a NumPy array, so you need to read it from the image and then rewrite it to the image after that you saved it.

You can do this with [pyexiv2](https://github.com/LeoHsiao1/pyexiv2) this module can be used for this task.

here some example of reading of metadata:

```
import pyexiv2
img = pyexiv2.Image(r'.\pyexiv2\tests\1.jpg')
data = img.read_exif()
img.close()
```

here an example of modify:

```
# Prepare the XMP data you want to modify
dict1 = {'Xmp.xmp.CreateDate': '2019-06-23T19:45:17.834',   # Assign a value to a tag. This will overwrite its original value, or add it if it doesn't exist
...          'Xmp.xmp.Rating': None}                            # Assign None to delete the tag
img.modify_xmp(dict1)
dict2 = img.read_xmp()       # Check the result
dict2['Xmp.xmp.CreateDate']
'2019-06-23T19:45:17.834'        # This tag has been modified
dict2['Xmp.xmp.Rating']
KeyError: 'Xmp.xmp.Rating'       # This tag has been deleted
img.close()
```

here you can find the [docs](https://github.com/LeoHsiao1/pyexiv2/blob/master/docs/Tutorial.md#read)