# Error while trying to get the EXIF tags of the image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, exif, piexif

I'm trying to get the EXIF tags of an JPG image. To do this, I'm using `piexif` module.
The problem is that I get an error - `KeyError`, saying this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PythonProjects/IMGDateByNameRecovery/recovery.py", line 98, in selectImages
    self.setExifTag(file_str)
  File "D:/PythonProjects/IMGDateByNameRecovery/recovery.py", line 102, in setExifTag
    exif = piexif.load(img.info["Exif"])
KeyError: 'Exif'
```

I've did everything as in the docs, here on some questions StackOverflow and on pypi website. Everything the same. My code:

```py
    img = Image.open(file)
    exif_dict = piexif.load(img.info["exif"])

    altitude = exif_dict['GPS'][piexif.GPSIFD.GPSAltitude]
    print(altitude)
```

How do I read the image's EXIF tags then? Am I doing it wrong?
Please, I'm so clueless. This is such a weird error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pillow only adds the `exif` key to the `Image.info` if EXIF data exists. So if the images has no EXIF data your script will return the error because the key does not exist.

You can see what image formats support the `info["exif"]` data in the [Image file formats documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html).

You could do something like this...

```py
img = Image.open(file)
exif_dict = img.info.get("exif")  # returns None if exif key does not exist

if exif_dict:
    exif_data = piexif.load(exif_dict)
    altitude = exif_data['GPS'][piexif.GPSIFD.GPSAltitude]
    print(altitude)
else:
    pass
    # Do something else when there is no EXIF data on the image.
```

Using `mydict.get("key")` will return a value of `None` if the key does not exist where as `mydict["key"]` will throw a `KeyError`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about it. Can I get an EXIF tag from a PNG file?

Comment: The docs are not clear on that. They mention EXIF for saving PNG's but not opening them. You can check by using `print(img.info)` to print the `info` dictionary on a PNG you know has EXIF data.

Comment: Okay. I have one more question. Can I modify the EXIF tag even if the image does not have any tags? Or maybe create default tags for the image and then modify just some of them?

Comment: Yes you can. EXIF data is a byte string you can turn it into a dictionary like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image) and merge it with a default dictionary or set missing keys. You will need to turn it back into a byte string if you are going to call the `save()` method and pass in the `exif` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have encoded metadata within the `MakerNotes`.
Make sure to install the following dependencies:

- pixeif
- Pillow

Then run the following code considering the image is `Image.png` and is in the same directory of the script:

```py
from PIL import Image
import piexif
import pickle

img = Image.open('Image.png')

exif_dict = img.info.get("exif") # returns None if exif key does not exist
if exif_dict:
  exif_data = piexif.load(exif_dict)
  raw = exif_data['Exif'][piexif.ExifIFD.MakerNote]
  tags = pickle.loads(raw)
  print(tags)
```