# How can I edit an image's "Date taken" value and a video's "Media created" value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, metadata, exif

On Windows, by right-clicking an image or video, then clicking on properties, then clicking on the "details" tab, origin information can be found about that file.
This is how that looks like for an image:

[image: "Date taken" of an image]

And this is how that looks like for a video:

[image: "Media created" of a video]

I want to edit the values of the "Date taken" and "Media created" keys with Python.

---

### What I've tried

- **Using the `Pillow` library**

This is my code:

```py
import piexif
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("test.jpg")
exif_dict = piexif.load(img.info['exif'])
exif_dict["Exif"][piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeOriginal] = u"2099:09:29 10:10:10"
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
img.save("test", "jpg", exif=exif_bytes)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 53, in <module>
    exif_dict = piexif.load(img.info["exif"])
KeyError: 'exif'
```

That's because [jpg images are not supported by Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#id5)

- **Using the `setctime` function from the `win32_setctime` module**

```py
from win32_setctime import setctime
setctime("test.jpg", 523434.342)
```

This method works only for videos, but not for images.
Also, this method works only for Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while trying to get the EXIF tags of the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58311162/error-while-trying-to-get-the-exif-tags-of-the-image)

Comment: @Karthik Thanks, but no. I've already explored that thread.

Comment: It clearly states that `exif` will only work if exif data exists. yours may not be the appropriate form..You can check this using any other image it should work in that case

Comment: I've tried with multiple images (all jpg), and it doesn't work. I bet it would work for supported file formats (like PNG, JPEG, etc.), but not for jpg:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#id5