# Python error upon exif data extraction via Pillow module: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, byte, exif

I am writing a piece of code to extract exif data from images using Python. I downloaded the `Pillow` module using `pip3` and am using some code I found online:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

imagename = "path to file"
image = Image.open(imagename)

exifdata = image.getexif()

for tagid in exifdata:
    tagname = TAGS.get(tagid, tagid)
    data = exifdata.get(tagid)
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        data = data.decode()
    print(f"{tagname:25}: {data}")
```

On some images this code works. However, for images I took on my Olympus camera I get the following error:

```
GPSInfo                  : 734
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_pathname redacted_", line 14, in <module>
    data = data.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 30: invalid continuation byte
```

When I remove the `data = data.decode()` part, I get the following:

```
GPSInfo                  : 734
PrintImageMatching       : b"PrintIM\x000300\x00\x00%\x00\x01\x00\x14\x00\x14\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x008\x01\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00P\x01\x00\x00\x10\x00`\x01\x00\x00 \x00\xb4\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\xff\x00\x00\x00\x02\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x03\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x04\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x05\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x07\x01\x80\x80\x80\x00\x10\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x02\xf8\x01\x00\x00\r\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x02\xd6\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\xff\x00\x00\x00\x02\x03\x83\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x83\x00\x00\x00\x06\x03\x83\x00\x00\x00\x10\x03\x83\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x11\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\x0b\x0f\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\x97\x05\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\xb0\x08\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\x01\x1c\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00^\x02\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\x8b\x00\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\xcb\x03\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\xe5\x1b\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x05\x05\x00\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x05\x05\x05\x00\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
ResolutionUnit           : 2
ExifOffset               : 230
ImageDescription         : OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA         
Make                     : OLYMPUS CORPORATION    
Model                    : E-M10MarkII     
Software                 : Version 1.2                    
Orientation              : 1
DateTime                 : 2020:02:13 15:02:57
YCbCrPositioning         : 2
YResolution              : 350.0
Copyright                : 
XResolution              : 350.0
Artist                   :
```

How should I fix this problem? Should I use a different Python module?

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of libraries like [`exif`](https://pypi.org/project/exif/), or are you just doing this for fun?

Comment: I've heard of **exif** but am unsure if that would solve my problem. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging and figured out the answer to the problem I posted about. I originally postulated that the rest of the metadata was in the byte data:

```
b"PrintIM\x000300\x00\x00%\x00\x01\x00\x14\x00\x14\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x008\x01\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00P\x01\x00\x00\x10\x00`\x01\x00\x00 \x00\xb4\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\xff\x00\x00\x00\x02\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x03\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x04\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x05\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x07\x01\x80\x80\x80\x00\x10\x01\x83\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x02\xf8\x01\x00\x00\r\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x02\xd6\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\xff\x00\x00\x00\x02\x03\x83\x00\x00\x00\x03\x03\x83\x00\x00\x00\x06\x03\x83\x00\x00\x00\x10\x03\x83\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x11\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\x0b\x0f\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\x97\x05\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\xb0\x08\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\x01\x1c\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00^\x02\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\x8b\x00\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\xcb\x03\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\xe5\x1b\x00\x00\x10'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x05\x05\x00\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x05\x05\x05\x00\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x00\x00@@\x80\x80\xc0\xc0\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

That assumption wasn't correct. Although the above is metadata, it simply isn't the metadata I am looking for (in my case the `FocalLength` attribute). Rather it appears to be Olympus specific metadata. The answer to my solution was to find all the metadata. I found a piece of code that worked very well in [Stack Overflow: In Python, how do I read the exif data for an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image).

I used the following code by [Nicolas Gervais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10908375/nicolas-gervais):

```
import os,sys
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

for (k,v) in Image.open(sys.argv[1])._getexif().items():
        print('%s = %s' % (TAGS.get(k), v))
```

I replaced `sys.argv[1]` with the path name to the image file.

### Alternate Solution

As [MattDMo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426065/mattdmo) mentioned, there are also specific libraries for reading EXIF data in Python. One that I found that look promising is [ExifRead](https://pypi.org/project/ExifRead/) which can be download by typing the following in the terminal:

```
pip install ExifRead
```