# adding a comment to a jpeg file using python

Tags: python, jpeg

I want to write a python program that adds a comment to a jpeg file. I've read that a comment in a jpeg file is signaled by the marker 0xfffe. Thus, can I just open the file and append this marker with whatever comment I want following it? My code looks something like this:

```
file = open("someimage.jpg", "a+b")
file.write("\xff\xfeCOMMENT")
file.close()
```

Does it matter if my comment is after the end of file marker (0xffd9)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work (it will append text beyond the part needed to store the image).

A more sophisticated approach would read the JPG file format and add a comment in EXIF fields.  See this StackOverflow discussion:  [Exif manipulation library for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765396/exif-manipulation-library-for-python)

See [pyexiv](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/) for python bindings to *exiv2*, a tool for reading and writing image metadata.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer uses EXIF fields. If a standard JPEG comment is needed, you'll need to insert the payload length:

Two bytes giving the-length-of-the-comment-in-bytes-plus-2 as a big-endian (unsigned short) integer must be inserted between the <kbd>FF FE</kbd> bytes and the comment.

For example, the sequence of bytes corresponding to a comment <kbd>Hello</kbd> is <kbd>FF FE</kbd><kbd>00 07</kbd><kbd>48 65 6C 6C 6F</kbd> because the length of the payload (unsigned short + comment) is 7 bytes. If an optional C-style null-terminator is wanted, it's <kbd>FF FE</kbd><kbd>00 08</kbd><kbd>48 65 6C 6C 6F 00</kbd>.

The comment segment should strictly be before the end-of-file marker (<kbd>FF D9</kbd>) though some image viewers may understand extra data after the marker.

For details, see [How do text comments in JPG files work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447201/how-do-text-comments-in-jpg-files-work).