# Save JPEG comment using Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg

I need to save an Image in Python (created as a Numpy array) as a JPEG file, while including a "comment" in the file with some specific metadata. This metadata will be used by another (third-party) application and is a simple ASCII string. I have a sample image including such a "comment", which I can read out using Pillow (PIL), via the `image.info['comment']` or the `image.app['COM']` property. However, when I try a simple round-trip, i.e. loading my sample image and save it again using a different file name, the comment is no longer preserved. Equally, I found no way to include a comment in a newly created image.

I am aware that EXIF tags are the preferred way to save metadata in JPEG images, but as mentioned, the third-party application only accepts this data as a "comment", not as EXIF, which I cannot change. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283798/adding-a-comment-to-a-jpeg-file-using-python) question, I looked into the binary structure of my sample file and found the comment at the start of the file, after a few bytes of some other (meta)data. I do however not know a lot about binary file manipulation, and also I was wondering if there is a more elegant way, other than messing with the binary...

EDIT: minimum example:

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(path)  # where path is the path to the sample image

# this prints the desired metadata if it is correctly saved in loaded image
print(img.info["comment"])

img.save(new_path)  # save with different file name
img.close()

# now open to see if it has been saved correctly
new_img = Image.open(new_path)
print(new_img.info['comment'])  # now results in KeyError
```

I also tried `img.save(new_path, info=img.info)`, but this does not seem to have an effect. Since `img.info['comment']` appears identical to `img.app['COM']`, I tried `img.save(new_path, app=img.app)`, again does not work.

Comment: I'm not clear where you want your *"round trip"* to pass through. Can you add a simple [mcve] of what you want to do please?

Answer (score 3):

Just been having a play with this and I couldn't see anything directly in Pillow to support this.  I've found that the `save()` method supports a parameter called `extra` that can be used to pass arbitrary bytes to the output file.

We then just need a simple method to turn a comment into a valid JPEG segment, for example:

```
import struct
from PIL import Image

def make_jpeg_variable_segment(marker: int, payload: bytes) -> bytes:
    "make a JPEG segment from the given payload"
    return struct.pack('>HH', marker, 2 + len(payload)) + payload

def make_jpeg_comment_segment(comment: bytes) -> bytes:
    "make a JPEG comment/COM segment"
    return make_jpeg_variable_segment(0xFFFE, comment)

# open source image
with Image.open("foo.jpeg") as im:
    # save out with new JPEG comment
    im.save('bar.jpeg', extra=make_jpeg_comment_segment("hello world".encode()))

# read file back in to ensure comment round-trips
with Image.open('bar.jpeg') as im:
    print(im.app['COM'])
    print(im.info['comment'])
```

Note that in my initial attempts I tried appending the comment segment at the end of the file, but Pillow wouldn't load this comment even after calling the `.load()` method to force it to load the entire JPEG file.

Update: The upcoming version Pillow version 9.4.0 will support this by passing a `comment` parameter while saving, e.g.:

```
with Image.open("foo.jpeg") as im:
  im.save('bar.jpeg', comment="hello world")
```

hopefully that makes things easier!

Comment: have turned this into an issue upstream: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6773

Comment: that issue has just been closed, 9.4 will contain code to make this much easier