# Highgui.imread read rotated image

Tags: android, opencv

I am using camera to capture an image on my phone which use Android 4.03  and opencv for android 2.4.3

In my application I am reading the image from disk using Highgui.imread

But the problem is the function is rotating the image always in contrast to the actual saved image!

```
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Mat img = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());
            if(img!=null)
                n.detectDocument(img.getNativeObjAddr());
```

and in native side

```
jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_example_superemr_NSuperEMR_detectDocument(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jlong addr)
{
    Mat* image = (Mat*) addr;
    imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/work/hala.jpg",*image);
    return NULL;
}
```

How can I read the image in the correct position?

Answer (score 1):

imread decodes the JPG metadata differently than the image viewer you're using.

Mobile photos have the "Orientation" [EXIF](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html) set.  This is seen in Chrome with [photo1](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=i3uvdf&s=8#.VAJEhWSwI0g) and [photo2](http://oi59.tinypic.com/i3uvdf.jpg) on tinypic.

Not sure how to read and handle the EXIF flags correctly in C++, but in python a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765396/exif-manipulation-library-for-python).

Haven't tried this, but you may consider reading the image with another library, saving as a png and then reading into opencv.

PS: Saw this was an old post, but this came up in my search result when I ran into the same issue, so maybe it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use imagemagick to first auto-orient the image. This will change orientation metadata to 1( or Top-Left) and change the orientation of image(rotate and mirror, whichever is necessary).

Checking orientation metadata: identify -format '%[exif:orientation]'

Auto-Orient Image: convert -auto-orient