# Exif reading library

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, exif

Is there an exif library out there for Python 3.x? It seems every exif library I run into is for Python 2.x only. I don't need anything too fancy. Just reading the values is enough.

Comment: It's kind of cheating, but we call [Phil Harvey's exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) from Python using subprocess with the `-json -fast -@ argfile` options. It's simple and complete, and it's fast when you need process thousands of images in batches (as we do).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Option 1. Use pyexiv2.  See: [pyexiv2 Bug #824440: Python 3 support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyexiv2/+bug/824440)  You need boost-python for py3k and also to manually apply the patch posted at the end of the bug above, but aside from that it works.  Probably easiest to get up and running under latest Ubuntu.

Option 2. Use [PIL](https://github.com/sloonz/pil-py3k)  Downside: this branch/fork doesn't seem to be actively developed.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

image = Image.open("test.jpg")
exif = image._getexif()
# decode exif using TAGS
```

Option 3. Use PythonMagick

```
from PythonMagick import Image

img = Image("image.jpg")
print img.attribute("EXIF:Orientation")
```

See also: [Exif manipulation library for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765396/exif-manipulation-library-for-python)

Comment: Can you test this on this Question, download the images, and try to get the ImageDescription. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173902/how-to-get-image-title-in-python-django

Answer (score 5):

For reference, the [pyexiv2 homepage](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/) now has a deprecation warning which points to [Gexiv2](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2), a GObject-introspection based wrapper around libexiv2 (the same library pyexiv2 wraps) specifically for the purpose of Python 3.x support.

Unfortunately, at the time of writing, installation of Gexiv2 is still painful and thus far I've been unable to get it working on Ubuntu Precise (looks like the libs are out of date - probably serves me right for sticking around on an LTS...), so PIL is still the best option for reading EXIF tags in Python 3.