# Tagging jpegs in python

Tags: python, tags, jpeg

Is it possible to

1. Check jpeg file tags
2. Add new jpeg tags toa  file

in windows using python?

Thanks

Comment: 1. [Yes.](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) 2. [Yes.](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) [Next](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4764932/78845)?

Comment: See also [Exif reading library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14046303/78845) and other linked questions.