# How can I read Exiftags from string using PIL library?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on a project where I get the exiftags metadata (includes image system as well as custom data) as part of an API endpoint. I need to know how do I extract/parse the exiftags if the tags is being received as a string. I am referring to [Exif manipulation library for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765396/exif-manipulation-library-for-python)

But for me I don't have the image. I get the inforamtion as part of an endpoint something like this:

```
message: "description goes here",
metadata: "a:7:{s:4:"exif";a:27:"postgroup";a:1:{s:3:"key";s:5:"41926";}s:3:"key";s:5:"41926";i:1;s:5:"41926";}",
offensive: 0..............
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance on retrieving the exiftags from a string ideally if possible in python using PIL library. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was there something about this answer that you didn't understand? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10134835/5987

Comment: It was my understanding that the example in the above thread needs an image to get the exiftags, but for me I dont have the image, I get the exiftags as string (basically as an value from the one of our vendors endpoint). I dont really need the image/system metadata as such but I need some custom metadata which is also with in the exiftags string.