# Is it possible to write EXIF data using Python 3 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, exif

I have a set (hundreds) of JPEG files that I need to equip (WRITE access) with EXIF data. For that I would like to use `python3` so I can batch process the files and incorporate it in my data flow.

I have looked at [Gexiv2](http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/gexiv2/wiki), but I haven't found a way to use it in Windows.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765396/exif-manipulation-library-for-python) from 2009 is similar, but mine is more specific.

**Question**:
How can I write EXIF data to multiple JPEG files using `python3` in Windows?

I would prefer not to use commercial software.

Comment: You can use pillow for windows - .exe installer here.  But I don't see it being able to EXIF data: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0#downloads

Comment: This is a good question, I hope it gets reopened.

Comment: Four years later, and this is still a good question.  Several hours of searching, and all I can find are old Python 2 libraries, or Linux only packages.  All the SO questions on the topic have been closed as off topic, which is less than helpful.