# Using libexif in Python

Tags: python, c, ctypes, exif

I'm writing a Python-based [web] application that needs to be able to read and write EXIF data.

[libexif](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/) seems to have all the right ingredients, but I can't work out how (or if) I could access it access it by using Python's [ctypes library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)? I'm new to C, suppose I need *see* a `.so` for this to work?

Comment: Since you need to manipulate EXIFs this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765396/exif-manipulation-library-for-python

Comment: Appreciate there are some Python-based solutions out there, from what i've seen `libexif` appears the most feature-full, and principally I'm just curious if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be running on an os that you can obtain the required library, to download the .h files, (usually the -dev package gives you these).

Then you need to work your way through the ctypes tutorial found [here](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html) which explains all the steps you need to take.