# Reading long exif tags in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif, exiftool

I'm trying to read the EXIF info for microscope images like this one: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3816350/E3-9.tif

I am most interested in the "Image Description" tag because it contains information about the scale of the image. I have successfully loaded the EXIF info using the exifread package:

```
import exifread

f = open('E3-9.tif', 'rb')
exif_info = exifread.process_file(f)

for tag in exif_info.keys():
    print "Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, exif_info[tag])
```

However, the Image Description is cutoff in the output and I cannot figure out how to display the entire "Image ImageDescription" field. Any idea how I can do this?

BTW, I tried using PIL to read the EXIF info (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image)) using this code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

img = Image.open('E3-9.tif')
exif_data = img._getexif()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/..../2014-01-02 - Read scale from tif file.py", line 22, in <module>
    exif_data = img._getexif()
  File "/Users/danhickstein/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 512, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _getexif
```

I have also tried exiftool on the command line, but it also slightly cuts off the Image Description field.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you test this on this Question, download the images, and try to get the ImageDescription. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173902/how-to-get-image-title-in-python-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the hilariously slow and inefficient method of calling exiftool on the command line using subprocess.check_output. Not my finest hour, but it works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import subprocess, glob, re

def get_magnification(filename):
    p = subprocess.check_output('exiftool -tab %s'%filename,shell=True) 

    xpix = float(re.findall('XpixCal=\d*.\d*',p)[0][8:])
    ypix = float(re.findall('YpixCal=\d*.\d*',p)[0][8:])

    mag = int(re.findall('p.\d+',p)[0][2:])

    return xpix,ypix,mag

xpix,ypix,mag = get_magnification('E3-9.tif')

print 'X pixels per nm: %.3f'%(xpix)
print 'Y pixels per nm: %.3f'%(ypix)
print 'Magnification:   %ix'%(mag)
```

Answer (score 0):

The metadata you're looking may be part of the image's IPTC metadata, not EXIF. If so, you'll need a different Python module to read it. Take a look at ["Exif manipulation library for python [closed]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765396/exif-manipulation-library-for-python) for recommendations that include IPTC data.

Comment: Makes sense. But it seems that exifread can access that information, I just cannot figure out how to get it to display the whole field.

Comment: Yes, I'm not certain, and clarified the tone of my answer. (I base it somewhat on Photoshop's interpretation of the file.) I also think the file may be corrupted. `php -r "var_dump(exif_read_data('E3-9.tif')['ImageDescription']);"` returns `##fv3"m=2.091Philips CM100`, without even a variable type which is *incredibly* odd.

Comment: Hahaha, the instrument that created the file looks like it's about 100 years old, so it doesn't surprise me that the file isn't perfect :). ImageJ correctly displays the info as:
Philips CM100
12/17/13
2:18:55 p
28500
51
100.0
Imaging
XpixCal=2.091
YpixCal=2.091
Unit=nm
##fv3

Answer (score 0):

You have to use exif_info[tag].values to get the full ImageDescription